# WCF Tracing throws XML Exception "encountered unexpected character 'j'" on call function using JSONP

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, parsing, jsonp

I have a WCF Service with a function named GetTrackingLink:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public BasicResponse GetTrackingLink(string orderID)
{
    BasicResponse response = new 
    if (orderID == null)
        response.Status = "null";
    else
        response.Status = "not null";
    return response;
}
```

I call this function from another page, using the following script:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://localhost:14113/Service1.svc/GetTrackingLink',
crossDomain: true,
global: true,
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: {
"orderID": "006-0000001"        
},
success: function (result) {
console.log("success");
},
error: function (result) {
console.log("error");
}
};
```

The call is alright and data is sent correctly to GetTrackingLink. The problem is that I activated WCF tracing using the following config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Critical, Error, Warning, Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\inetpub\logs\RAFProdTraces2.svclog"></add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="messages" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\inetpub\logs\RAFProdTracesMessages2.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

...and after each call to GetTrackingLink, I find in RAFProdTraces2.svclog the following error: System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered unexpected character 'j'.

I know this happens because JSONP sends the callback with the request, which looks like this:

```
GET /Service1.svc/GetTrackingLink?callback=jQuery1102024896297114901245_1383152659468&orderID=006-0000001
```

Therefore, the 'j' from 'jQuery' causes WCF diagnosis to throw an exception (it's that 'j' because I replaced it with other characters repeated times and the new thrown exceptions had the characters that I used to replace the 'j' with).

My question is, is there any way to get System Diagnosis to parse the request correctly and ignore the "callback=jQuery1102024896297114901245_1383152659468" part?

Or is there any other way to get rid of this exception?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know its been many months since you sent this but since I have found no reply and am sure others have the same problem, here is my solution to the issue.

The reason for issue because WCF doesn't like the returned json. The problem is that the returned json is something like the following:

```
jQuery1102024896297114901245_1383152659468([{"PropertyTypeCode":"Unit","PropertyType":"Unit / Tower Block"}])
```

With the callback function as a wrapper. What I have done is built a workaround to create the json programmatically and return the data as a stream so that wcf won't care about the format.

So function would be e.g:

```
System.IO.Stream GetTrackingLink(string callback, string countryCode ...)
```

Then in the function if your object is "response":

```
string jsonClient = GetJsonString(response, callback);
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonClient));
```

And the function:

```
private string GetJsonString(object myObject, string callback)

    {
        var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return callback + "(" + s.Serialize(myObject) + ")";
    }
```

Then WCF will return a json string with the callback wrapper and not have any formatting complaints. Hope this helps a few people with this issue.

Harel